# How can I prove this is the image of a preimage?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we suppose that $A\subset X$ and $B\subset Y$ and that $f$ is surjective, how can we prove that $f(f^{-1}(B))=B$?

I started with the definition of image and preimage, by fixing a $y\in f(f^{-1}(B))$. Then, from the definition of image there exists 
$a\in f^{-1}(B)$ such that $y=f(a)$ and by definition of preimage $f(a)\in B$. Therefore, $y\in B$. So this shows that $f(f^{-1}(B)) \subset B$ but how can I prove equality? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have shown that $f(f^{-1}(B))\subseteq B$ - so now show that $B\subseteq f(f^{-1}(B))$ - this is a possible approach.

Comment: You need surjectivity for the other part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove the other direction, let $y \in B$. Then $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in X$, this means $x$ is in $f^{-1}(y)$ which is a subset of $f^{-1}(B)$. So $x\in f^(-1)(B)$, and this again means that: $y$ is in $f(f^{-1}(B))$. So $B$ is contained in $f(f^{-1}(B))$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what may be lost when you pass from $B$ to $f(f^{-1}(B))$. The only part that may be lost is when $B$ is not in the image of $f$, in which case $f(f^{-1}(B))$ would be strictly contained in $B$. This is why surjectivity is required.

Now that the intuition is in order, a formal proof can be done.

Suppose $y \in B$. By surjectivity, there exists $x$ such that $f(x) = y$, i.e., $x \in f^{-1}(y)$. Therefore, $y = f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(y)) \subseteq f(f^{-1}(B))$.